# NuGet.Server vs. Network Share

Tags: nuget

What are the benefits to using NuGet.Server, as opposed to a shared directory on the network, for serving up NuGet packages internally?

Note: I'm not looking for opinion, I want to know what NuGet.Server offers, technically, that you wouldn't get from a folder, based on the assumption that accessing the NuGet packages externally is not a requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio can handle nugets stored in shared directory but I couldn't force command line clients to read from such a repository.

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to access a windows share from a linux server or from a docker container. By having a Nuget server it's just https